# How to perform this action of creating new edges from verts (video included)

Tags: modeling

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LnYG5V4ULA&list=PLkzE48dEJCB1T9WC7slXaQ6yyfhzuU4lN&index=13&t=0s

At 0.13 seconds in (please watch at 0.25 speed) He selects verts along a vertical edgeloop, then selects a vert on an intersecting horizontal edgeloop and somehow creates a new set of verts parallel to the selected vertical vertices, from the last selected vert (on the horizontal edgeloop)

What is the tool/term/shortcut for this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He has enabled the *Snapping* option (*Vertex* mode) and the *Auto Merge* option (top right of the 3D view > *Options*), then he selects the edge:

[image]

He extrudes and point out the vertex he wants to snap to:

[image]

And it snaps:

[image]

Comment: wonderful, thank you. Never even knew about the auto merge, as I had been right clicking and merging by distance manually. Incredible software! Thanks

Comment: you could also do the operation without auto merge and make a merge by distance at the end to make sure you don't have any overlapping vertices, also you don't have to enable the Snapping option, you can simply press Ctrl while moving your vertices, just make sure your Snapping option is on Vertex though

Comment: Thank you, Moonboots, that's great to know